# Move Cursor positioning not working on textarea with enscroll plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have applied the enscroll plugin for a textarea:

```
$('textarea[name="text_area_name"]').enscroll({
    showOnHover: true, 
    scrollIncrement: 20, 
    minScrollbarLength: 25, 
    verticalTrackClass: 'track3',
    verticalHandleClass: 'handle3'
});
```

now the problem is the space and the cursor positions (left, up, right, down arrows) not working for that that textarea. For spacing, I have applied the following code and its working perfect to add spacing during writing on text area:

```
$('#text_area_name').keydown(function(e) {
    var event = e.which || e.keyCode;

    // Handle Space button       
    if (event === 32) {
        var data = $(this).val();
        data += " ";
        $(this).val(data);
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
textarea{
    width: 190px !important;
    height: 50px;
    resize: none;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding:10px;
    background-color: #EAEAEA;
}
```

But I don't have any idea how to apply the arrow keycodes and change the position of the cursor with. Can anyone guide me to achieve that?

**UPDATE:** I noticed that the dynamic generated scroll moves when I click on the textarea and press the up and down key, then I think the problem with in enscroll plugin but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's **Right or Not** but i have changed the part of the core enscroll plugin and it's work for me :

```
keyHandler = function( event ) {
    var $this = $( this ),
        data = $this.data( 'enscroll' ),
        scrollIncrement;

    // don't handle events that have just bubbled up
    if ( event.target === this && data ) {
        scrollIncrement = data.settings.scrollIncrement;

        switch( event.keyCode ) {
            /*case 32: // space*/
            case 34: // page down
                scrollVertical( this, $this.height() );
                return false;
            case 33: // page up
                scrollVertical( this, -$this.height() );
                return false;
            case 35: // end
                scrollVertical( this, this.scrollHeight );
                return false;
            case 36: // home
                scrollVertical( this, -this.scrollHeight );
                return false;
            /*case 37: // left
                scrollHorizontal( this, -scrollIncrement );
                return false;
            case 38: // up
                scrollVertical( this, -scrollIncrement );
                return false;
            case 39: // right
                scrollHorizontal( this, scrollIncrement );
                return false;
            case 40: // down
                scrollVertical( this, scrollIncrement );
                return false;
                                    */
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

this is the function that handles all the keys that i was struggled for( space -> 32 and 37 to 40 direction keys ), i just disable the associated keys.

#### And now its working for me ;)

### But is there a way to disable these keys outside from core files? with using of plugin reference etc.?